# PHP mysqli_stmt::get_result() is undefined method

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

Researching, looking on stackoverflow, looking through Google, I have found several people with the same problem, and the solution generally is "Available only with mysqlnd."

And so I look around and poked at some code, but as far as I can tell, mysqlnd IS enabled on my server. So that is why I do **not** believe this is a **duplicate**.

```
$id = $stmt->get_result();
```

That line of code, for whatever reason, seems to be causing a hiccup in my application that works perfectly on my local XAMPP server. I am figuring it's some sort of issue with my public server configuration, but I cannot figure out what.

PHP is throwing this error:

```
[18-Mar-2014 15:39:27 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error:  
Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in 
/home/PATH/PAGE.php on line 47
```

Again, my code works fine on my local server. Here's some snapshots of my `phpinfo()`...

[image: MySQLi Seems to Exist...]

[image: MySQLnd Seems to Exist...]

And just for good measure, my PHP version is `5.4.22`. And, finally, running `php -i | grep mysqlnd` in system console gives me `mysqlnd => enabled`.

So... What's up? What am I missing? Thankyou for your consideration. I hope this can help others along the way, too. More code (as requested)...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usr', 'pass', 'table');
$chkid = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE student_id = ? LIMIT 1";
if ($mysqli->connect_error) { //We'll catch an error or two here.
  die("{CNCT}");
} 
$arrays = json_decode($_POST['data'], true); //Here, we take the JSON string and create PHP arrays
for ($x=0; $x<=((count($arrays))-1); $x++) { //We count the array
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($chkid);
  $inputz = ($arrays[$x]['id']);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $inputz);
  $stmt->execute();
  $id = $stmt->get_result(); //THIS LINE
  $stmt->close();
  $row = $id->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
}
```

I do hope I appropriately cut out everything I needed to without screwing up the code. It is working on my local XAMPP server.

Comment: I think get_result() doesn't work if you don't have libmysqlnd isntalled.

Comment: What does `var_dump($stmt)` tell you?

Comment: You need to post more code than simply the line that the error indicates. We need to see how `$stmt` has been initialized.

Comment: tlenss, var_dump($stmt) gives me an object with a bunch of stuff in it. If you need it, I can paste it here. Sammitch, since you requested it, give me a moment I will promptly post more code. Keep in mind my code is working fine on my local server.

Comment: @Sammitch I've added some code to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things, I rebuilt Apache (in WHM, using EasyApache) with MySQL (**NOT** MySQL of the system) and MySQL Improved (MySQLi). Previously I had used a combination of MySQL (of the system) and MySQL Improved. After the build completed, everything was working like magic.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

It requires not only mysqlnd presence just by itself, but also mysqli has to be built specifically with mysqlnd support. To do so, PHP has to be built with configuration option

```
--with-mysqli=mysqlnd
```

in your phpinfo output, mysqlnd has to be mentioned under `Client API library version` item in mysqli section:

Good:
[image]

Not good:
[image]

I've no idea about XAMPP though, as I always build whole servers manually. It seems you need to look for  another version or another distribution.